# offset scroll to in html?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do the thing in html where you click on a link and it automatically scrolls to where you want in the page. Here is the button/link part of the code:

```
<li><a href="#Origins">Origins</a></li>
```

And then I have it link to this part of the page represented by this code:

```
<h3 id="Origins">Origins</h3>
```

This works perfectly fine, however, my header of the page at the top, which is h1, is set to fixed position.
So when you click the link, it goes too far down to where the header at the top is covering the "origins"
part of the page. I tried adding padding to the top of origins which works but then there is a lot of blank space
above "origins" in the page which I do not want. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need a full source so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Very very dirty thing you try : drop an anchor "origins" a few before your h3 .

Comment: Should I really upload the folder of the four files? I can do that I guess. I am new to this web site so I am not sure how to upload files.

Comment: Ok so I dropped an anchor a few lines up from where I want origins to go to but I feel like that is not good practice where I just put an anchor before every scroll to link. I am not experienced with javascript but I will explore the answer given below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with Javascript(example below requires jQuery, but could also be accomplished with Vanilla Javascript) by scrolling to the position of the `h3` minus the height of the `h1`:

```js
$(function() {
  var h1Height = $('h1').height(); // get height of h1 tag
  $('li a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var target = $(this.hash);
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - h1Height // scroll to h3 minus height of h1
      }, 1000);
      return false;
  });
});
```

```css
body,html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
h1{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  background:#fff;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
ul {
  margin:60px 0 0;
}
.space, h3 {
  margin:1000px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Heading</h1>

<ul><li><a href="#Origins">Origins</a></li></ul>

<div class="space"></div>

<h3 id="Origins">Origins</h3>
```

Comment: Great answer, just it requires JQuery could to do it in Vanilla, or edit your answer to say it requires JQuery.

Answer (score 26):

**scroll-margin-top** did the trick for me.

```
<h1>Heading</h1>

<ul><li><a href="#Origins">Origins</a></li></ul>

<div class="space"></div>

<h3 id="Origins" style="scroll-margin-top: 7em;">Origins</h3>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top

Comment: that worked, but I wanted to mention that, for me, when I put the `<a>` tag on the same page for testing purposes it didn't. Instead if I clicked the URL from another page, it behaved correctly. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use scroll-margin-top.

```
h3[id] {
  scroll-margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

Visit https://css-tricks.com/fixed-headers-and-jump-links-the-solution-is-scroll-margin-top/

Answer (score 0):

I generally put an anchor where it's semantically correct, give it position relative, and push it up by the height of the header plus a few px.

Answer (score -1):

```js
  const el = document.getElementById('description');
  el.style.scrollMarginTop = '70px';
  el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).